# Fastest way to read website during high traffic (Avoid timeout)

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

Imagine a website that publishes an important news at an exact time. Let's take 00:00 UTC as an example.

Normally my requests to that website take around 100ms. But at 00:00 UTC, there is very high traffic on the website because everybody is spamming the reload button which makes my requests time out and I often have a 10 second delay until I get a response.

What are some things I could do to make my requests as fast as possible?
Is that even possible or do I have to be lucky that my request gets handled first by the server?

I already tried using http instead of https but the server returns 301 Moved permanently in that case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact the server administrators to see if they can give you priority access, say, through a different endpoint. .If there were a "I am more important" flag. it would .be useless because everybody would set it.

Comment: Unfortunately the server admins won't give priority access to anyone since it's supposed to be "fair". I thought that maybe I could somehow "preconnect" to the website at let's say 23:59 and then start reading the body exactly at 00:00. So I guess the best way to do it would be to spam the website with as many clients as possible to increase my chances?

Comment: (1) It depends on how the server decides what time your request occurred. You'll have to ask the server admins how they decide. We don't know. (2) Given your description, it sounds like the server admins are actively defending against people like you. Any obvious technical approach has probably already been blocked. At this point, you're just hacking the site, and there is no general-purpose solution.

Comment: I may as well just tell you which site I'm talking about. Important economic indicators (like the consumer/producer price index) are published every month on the website https://bls.gov and I'm trying to trade equities based on these news. I don't think they are actively defending against this type of behaviour since my requests don't get blocked. They just have to deal with so much traffic during the release that very often my requests take 10 seconds instead of 100 milliseconds. But I guess you're right that there is no general solution.

Comment: If there were a general solution, everybody would be using it, and nobody has gained anything.